# MATLAB plot point with color based on distance from line

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a set of `m` points and a set of `n` lines in 2D in MATLAB. Suppose the `n` lines are plotted in `n` colors, I need to plot each point with the color of the *average color* of the set of lines to which it is closest to. I can compute the distances of the points from the lines, but how do I set the color of the point using `scatter` to be a value weighted by the distances from the lines to which it is closest to?

Comment: Give each line an integer flag, and then use that as `C` index for `scatter`.

Comment: This won't plot the points with a color based on distances from the lines, shouldn't it involve using the distances from the lines to determine the color? I would also like to mention that number of points and lines are different.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Give each line an integer flag based on the closest line you have already calculated, and then use that as `C` index for `scatter`. E.g. all points closest to the bottom line get flag `1`, all points closest to the second line get flag `2` etc. That column you can use as `C` input to scatter to colour the points. (Apologies, I missed what the flag was based on in the first comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That example should help you:

```
clear all;
close all;

m = 20; %number of points
markerSize = 25;

%example points
a=rand(2,m);
a(:,m-1) = [0;0]; % this point will be purple
a(:,m-2) = [1;0]; % this point will be blue
a(:,m-3) = [0;1]; % this point will be red

%line x=0 is red
%line y=0 is blue;
f1 =figure(1);
hold on;
for i = 1:m
    pointColor = [1-a(1,i) 0 1-a(2,i)]; % rgb format - calculate distance here
    % [0 0 0] - black , [1 1 1] - white
    % pointColor=(lineColor1*distance1 + lineColor2*distance2+...)/numberOfClosestLines;
    scatter(a(1,i),a(2,i),markerSize, pointColor)
end
```